# Complexity classes generated by differential equations

Tags: computational-complexity, quantum-computation

The quantum computer can be represented as a turing machine that sets up initial conditions for Schrodinger-like equation plus a fast ($O(1)$) solver for that equation.

Is there a general study for computational models using other differential equations, and the complexity classes they generate?

Alternatively what makes Schrodinger equation special in this context is it the way initial conditions are specified, or our assumption that it holds to arbitrary high precision. (It seems the analog of quantum fourier transform should be possible to do with Maxwell equations too, if they were exact).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that makes quantum mechanics special is that the Hilbert space for an $n$-particle system is essentially the tensor product, rather than the sum, of the Hilbert spaces for the individual particles.  Thus the dynamics can take place in a space of very high dimension.  Quantum
computing is all about trying to take advantage of this.